# is there any apache storm cluster size limit?

Tags: apache-storm

I presume that having more nodes in a storm cluster increases the "keep-topology-alive" intra-cluster communication.

Given that the topology works fine with 10 nodes (2 or 4 CPU, 4GB RAM) for small data, can we scale the topology to 1,000 or 10,000 nodes and still be competitive for (very) big data? Is there any known practical limit?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scaling of Storm cluster is limited by the speed of state storage in Zookeeper, most of it is "heartbeats" from workers. The theoretical limit is more or less 1,200 nodes (depends on the disk speed, 80MB/s write speed considered here). Obviously using a faster HDD will make things scale more.

However, people at Yahoo are working on In-memory store for worker heartbeats. Their solution will increase the limit to about 6,250 nodes using a GigabitE connections. 10Gigabit connections will increase this theoretical limit to 62,500 nodes. You can take a look at this Hadoop Summit 2015 [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/RobertEvans26/scaling-apache-storm-hadoop-summit-2015) from Bobby Evans for further details.